# Explanation of the Collections.max signature

Tags: java, generics

I was reading an article on Java Generics when I stumbled on this method signature:

```
static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll);
```

The part that I don't get is why we need to have

```
Collection<? extends T> coll
```

wouldn't

```
Collection<T> coll
```

do as well?

Could someone please explain why the following signature is not adequate?

```
static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> coll);
```

Thanks in advance for your replies. This keeps puzzling me for quite some time now..

Comment: For example you want to return a `Number`, but you also want to work with either `Double` or `Integer` collections too. This way you can specify at call site `Number`: `max<Number>(doubles)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, I think that would still work if we have Collection<T> as an argument.

Comment: My suspicion is that the only difference it makes in that context to use Collection<? extends T> coll instead of Collection<T> coll, is that with the former we limit the operations that can be performed on the list (e.g. adding a value of type T)

Comment: Using the wildcard prevents the method from inadvertently adding to or otherwise mutating the collection, since a *consumer* would need to require *super* (always remember the PECS mnemonic!)

Comment: Thus, I think Tom's reply verifies my suspucion

Comment: you can also see it follows the PECS principle. Coll is a provider of T, so it uses extends

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gábor is correct. The wildcard allows the static type of the returned object to differ from the declared parameter type of the collection you input. For example, given these classes:

```
interface S extends Comparable<S> {}
class A implements S {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final @NotNull S o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
class B implements S {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final @NotNull S o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
class Test {

    @Nullable
    static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T extendsMax(
            Collection<? extends T> coll) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<T> coll) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Observe what calls compile and what calls do not:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Collection<S> sColl = new ArrayList<>();
    final Collection<A> aColl = new ArrayList<>();
    final Collection<B> bColl = new ArrayList<>();

    final S s1 = Test.<S> extendsMax(sColl); // compiles, T = S, <? extends T> = S
    final S s2 = Test.<S> extendsMax(aColl); // compiles, T = S, <? extends T> = A
    final S s3 = Test.<S> extendsMax(bColl); // compiles, T = S, <? extends T> = B
    final A a1 = Test.<A> extendsMax(aColl); // compiles, T = A
    final B b1 = Test.<B> extendsMax(bColl); // compiles, T = B

    final S s4 = Test.<S> max(sColl); // compiles, T = S
    final S s5 = Test.<S> max(aColl); // does not compile, T = S, T != A
    final S s6 = Test.<S> max(bColl); // does not compile, T = S, T != B

    final S s7 = Test.max(aColl); // compiles, but because T = A, and A 
                                  // can be assigned to S
}
```

So the wildcard allows for some flexibility. While you *can* omit the wildcard (and to be honest, I can't think of a place off the top of my head where the wildcard is required), there is a reason it is there.

---

Tom is also incorrect. You can add `null` to collections with a wildcard (if the collection supports `add()` in the first place):

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(null); // compiles, and should execute just fine
```

And because `add()`, `remove()`, and most other mutators in the `Collection` interface are  optional operations, it wouldn't be safe to mutate the collection anyways through those methods if the parameter is just declared as a `Collection`. In addition, it's generally possible to use `iterator().remove()` or something of the sort to remove elements from collections regardless of whether they were declared with a wildcard, especially for the ones already included in the Java Collections Framework.

So while a wildcard does limit what you can do with a collection, it should *not* be used as a way to prevent changes to a collection.

Comment: `Test.<S> max(aColl); // does not compile` of course it does not. `T = S`, and `aColl` is `Collection<A>`. But as you mentioned later, you don't need the `<S>` to explicit `T`

Comment: @njzk2 The point was that the wildcard-less `max()` call would work in this situation, but not for the reason that one might expect.

Comment: true. `T` would be `A`, because of `aColl`, and not `S` because of the assignment.

Comment: I still don't get the point "The wildcard allows the static type of the returned object to differ from the declared parameter type of the collection you input." In your example you've proved that the code doesn't compile when explicitly using .<S>, but how does the <? extends T> help in the returned type to differ?

Comment: I'd appreciate it though if someone can post a scenario where the wildcard version is actually required

Comment: Thanks @user3580294. It is represented in a much cleaner way. And I also forgot about the `remove` method for mutating.

Comment: @GáborBakos `Collections.swap(…)` or `Collections.sort(…)` also work with wildcard types. There’s also `clear()` to remove all elements.

Comment: @Holger you are right, those can also mutate. (Of course I also wrap things in unmodifiable collections when I need non-modifiability, my habit is just for the easier tracking of this.)