# Practical use of Collections.max() signature

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

This is a follow up question to [Explanation of `Collections.max()` signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484339/explanation-of-the-collections-max-signature), where the accepted answer does not dive into the practical reason for this wildcard.

The `max` method takes a `Collection<? extends T>` and I am unable to think of a practical case where this wildcard helps.

I even referred [Oracle More fun with wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html) where it states that

> In general, if you have an API that only uses a type parameter T as an
>   argument, its uses should take advantage of lower bounded wildcards (?
>   super T). Conversely, if the API only returns T, you'll give your
>   clients more flexibility by using upper bounded wildcards (? extends
>   T).

But I still didn't get it. Even [Java Generics and Collections](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do) book does not speak much about the reason behind this wildcard.

Is there a practical use of this? A real world use case would be great.

Comment: Perhaps there is no practical reason at all? Just following the general PECS principle? At least I can't think of any.

Comment: [**Very related question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488357/why-is-t-bound-by-object-in-the-collections-max-signature).

Answer (score 5):

Imagine these two signatures:

```
static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max1(Collection<T> coll);
static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max2(Collection<? extends T> coll);
```

Now, let's try to construct functions of type.

```
Function<Collection<java.sql.Timestamp>, java.util.Date>

// This doesn't work:
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Date> f0 = 
    (Collection<Timestamp> col) -> Test.<Date>max1(col);

// This works:
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Date> f1 = 
    (Collection<Timestamp> col) -> Test.<Date>max2(col);
```

As you can see, using explicit typing, one of the methods doesn't work any longer.

#### Type inference "hides" this problem in the "real world":

Of course, you could just omit the explicit binding of the generic type argument `Test.<Date>maxN()`:

```
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Date> f0 = 
    (Collection<Timestamp> col) -> Test.max1(col);
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Date> f1 = 
    (Collection<Timestamp> col) -> Test.max2(col);
```

Or even:

```
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Date> f2 = Test::max1;
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Date> f3 = Test::max2;
```

And type inference would work its magic, as all of the above compile.

#### Now why bother?

We should always bother about API consistency, as [pbabcdefp has said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30013433/521799). Imagine there was an additional `optionalMax()` method (just to handle the case of an empty argument collection):

```
static <T extends ...> Optional<T> optionalMax1(Collection<T> coll);
static <T extends ...> Optional<T> optionalMax2(Collection<? extends T> coll);
```

Now, you can clearly see that only the second variant is useful:

```
// Does not work:
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Optional<Date>> f0 = 
    (Collection<Timestamp> col) -> Test.optionalMax1(col);
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Optional<Date>> f2 = Test::max1;

// Works:
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Optional<Date>> f1 = 
    (Collection<Timestamp> col) -> Test.optionalMax2(col);
Function<Collection<Timestamp>, Optional<Date>> f3 = Test::optionalMax2;
```

With this in mind, the following API would feel very inconsistent, and thus wrong:

```
static <T extends ...> T max(Collection<T> coll);
static <T extends ...> Optional<T> optionalMax(Collection<? extends T> coll);
```

So, in order to be consistent (no matter if the typing is needed or not), the methods *SHOULD* be using the `Collection<? extends T>` signature. Always.

Answer (score 4):

One useful experiment is this:

```
static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max1(Collection<T> coll) {
    return max2(coll);
}

static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max2(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    return max1(coll);
}
```

The fact that this compiles shows that the two signatures accept precisely the same set of arguments.

In fact there are several redundant wildcards in the signatures of the `Collections` class.

For example, the wildcard is not needed in

```
static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T t)
```

and

```
static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src)
```

would have worked equally well if one or other (but not both) of the wildcards weren't there.

So why include them?

The `copy` example is a good one. The use of `super` emphasizes that `dst` is being used in a write-only sense and the use of `extends` emphasizes that `src` is being used in a read-only sense. Similarly in `fill`, the `super`, while not needed, emphasizes that the `list` is being written to, but not read. In `max`, the `extends` emphasizes that the `List` is being read but not written to. For methods where the `Collection` is both read and written to, such as

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

no wildcard is used.

So in summary, I don't think that there are any practical uses for the wildcard, but it is a good way of indicating the way that the `Collection` is used by the method.

Comment: Good experiment. I tried to find something that compiles with the `extends` but does not compile without it, but did not think of such a test to show that there is no such case. So unless manually fixing the type with `Collections.<TheType>max(...)` there indeed is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the practical use for it is more for API designers.

Take `Collections.addAll(Collection<? extends E>)` as an example. If the class `Student` and class `Teacher` would both extend from class `Person` you could not add a `List<Student>` or `List<Teacher>` to a `List<Person>` to which you would want to send some invitation.

Another practical use could be to prevent <strike>modifications</strike> adding non-null elements by fault (assume you have no other control over the type of the List from getNumberList()).

In your code you get a reference to a `List<Number>` and you want to prevent that by fault something is added to this List.

```
// this would compile
List<Number> workList = getNumberList();
workList.add(new Integer(42));

// this would not compile as ? might be List<Double>
List<? extends Number> workList = getNumberList();
workList.add(new Integer(42));
```

Comment: As was mentioned in an answer to another question, it doesn't really work well as a modification prevention technique because you can still add nulls and remove elements. `Collections.unmodifiableList()` is what should be used in such a situation.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov I agree. I changed my answer to be clear that is would only prevent at compile time to add non-null element. It was not ment as a bullet proof solution. `Collections.unmodifiableList()` on the other side would fail at runtime.